# Change keyboard layout from code in osx

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I use below code for change keyboard layout from code but occur below warning from second line.

```
//warning
Assigning to 'TISInputSourceRef' (aka 'struct __TISInputSource *') from 'const void *' discards qualifiers
```

---

```
//code
CFArrayRef sourceList = TISCreateInputSourceList (NULL, false);
TISInputSourceRef wantedSource= CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sourceList, 0);
TISSelectInputSource(wantedSource);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to cast the value returned by `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex`, which is of type `const void*`:

```
TISInputSourceRef wantedSource = (TISInputSourceRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sourceList, 0);
```